# Sub(P) is complete?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be some abstract category, and $P$ be any set valued presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$. I want to show that the set of subfunctors of $P$, $Sub(P)$, is actually a Heyting algebra.

For two subfunctor $s: S \rightarrow P$, $t: T \rightarrow P$ of $P$, one can define the join as $(S \vee T)(C) = S(C) \cup T(C)$. I tried to check that this definition indeed gives another presheaf, but I can't see how to define it on arrows because $S(C)$ and $T(C)$ can have non trivial intersection and yet be mapped to different sets through $f: D \rightarrow C$. Any advice?

Comment: It looks like the property as stated in Mac Lane and Moerdjik "Sheaves in geometry and logic", p.56 is false. They claim that under such pointwise definition of meet and join, one has $P \vee S = P$. Yet, if one follows the definition strictly, $(P \vee S)(C) = P(C) \cup S(C)$ that has a priori no reason to be strictly equal to $P(C)$. In Set, any injective map $S \rightarrow P$ being monic, there is no reason that $S(C)$ be contained in $P(C)$

Comment: The relevant definition of subfunctor here is the one where $S (C)$ is literally a subset of $P (C)$ and $s : S (C) \to P (C)$ is the inclusion.

Comment: Yes, I eventually understood that that's what they want. I think its a bad definition for "subobject".

Comment: Moreover, it seems that they also require (without telling it) that $S(f)(x) = T(f)(x)$ for all $x$ in $S(C) \cap T(C)$ and all $f: C' \rightarrow C$, which is once again a big constraint.

Comment: That's automatic if you define subfunctors the way I said.

Comment: Alright, because by naturality, all $S(f)$ are actually the restriction of $P(f)$.